# jQuery addClass whit multiple dashes

Tags: jquery

I'm unable to add these **two** classes: `list-group-item` and `list-group-item-action`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("ul:first").append('<li class="list-group-item">' + (filmi.Movies[0].Title) + '</li>')
.attr(filmi.Movies[0].imdbID)
.addClass(list-group-item list-group-item-action)
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing quotes from your [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) statement.

```
$(function(){
  $("ul:first").append('<li class="list-group-item">' + (filmi.Movies[0].Title) + '</li>')
  .attr(filmi.Movies[0].imdbID)
  .addClass('list-group-item list-group-item-action');
});
```

Comment: Trailing semicolon is missed.

Comment: @Alexander  Not any more, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add quotes to `addClass()` argument.

```
.addClass('list-group-item list-group-item-action');
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
.addClass('list-group-item list-group-item-action')
```

The quotes are what determines the class name.